# Как установить цвет фона у выбранного элемента ListView для лучшего восприятия?

Tags: java, android

Текст диалога с ListView:

```
protected void showTTDialog(final ArrayList<String> items, final int selected) {
    int count = items.size();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Расписания")
        .setSingleChoiceItems(items.toArray(new String[count]), selected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item+" "+items.get(item), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    builder.create().show();
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что так будет проще всего установить цвет выбранному элементу. "Color.BLUE" заменить на свой и готово.

```
ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
list.getChildAt(item).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item+" "+items.get(item), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Работает! Но, при вторичном нажатии предыдущую окраску в синий приходится очищать самому)

Comment: Да, можно попробывать сделать с помощью селекторов и checkbox-ов к примеру, если вдруг этот способ почему-то неусраивает)

Comment: Да, все устраивает. После нажатия на любой элемент предыдущие покраски обнуляю и использую как раз Ваше решение. Не получается следующее: как покрасить фон элемента диалога, который отмечается до нажатия(выбора)  "onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)"?!

Comment: Можно в адаптере в методе getViev проверять выбран или нет элемент и ставить фон или убирать его.